# why is my form validation not working with flask?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

for some reason even if any of the five forms dont exist, the form still submits. Here is the code below. The line that I am having problems with is the if not line

```
@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('/dashboard')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        first = encryption.encrypt(request.form['first'])
        last = encryption.encrypt(request.form['last'])
        userEmail = encryption.encrypt(request.form['email'])
        userUsername = encryption.sha256(request.form['username'])
        userPass = encryption.sha256(request.form['password'])
        if not (first or last or userUsername or userEmail or userPass):
            msg= 'Please Fill All Of The Forms'
            return render_template('register.html')
        else:
            dupCheck = dup_check(userEmail, userPass)
            #if user already exists in database, dont allow it to be added
            if dupCheck is True:
                msg = 'Email/username already present'
                return render_template('register.html', msg=msg)
            #if user does not exist, create session to add data to db
            user = parent_user(
                email=userEmail, 
                parent_user=userUsername, 
                parent_first=first, 
                parent_last=last,
                password = userPass
                )
            db.session.add(user)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect('/')
    return render_template('register.html')
```

Comment: `if not (first or last or userUsername or userEmail or userPass)` This will be false only if ALL of the items are blank.

Comment: Print the inputs after the if not line. What are you getting there?
Also try with "and" instead of "or", maybe it works...

Comment: As Jhon said above, if you have even just one input of the form, it will pass.

Comment: Also, it's possible that `encryption.sha256()` adds some padding bytes even if the input string is blank...